# How to change Material-UI TextFiled's border, text color and border color on hover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I'm not fully understanding how to customise MaterialUI components. After reading through the dos `https://material-ui.com/customization/components/` I understand how to customise using `classes` and `className`. I don't understand the advanced techniques - really confusing.

Here is an example I've found on codesandbox on customising TextFields `https://codesandbox.io/s/6rx8p?file=/demo.tsx:842-858`

e.g.

```
const CssTextField = withStyles({
  root: {
    '& label.Mui-focused': {
      color: 'green',
    },
    '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
      borderBottomColor: 'green',
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      '& fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'red',
      },
      '&:hover fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'yellow',
      },
      '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'green',
      },
    },
  },
})(TextField);
```

From the above example where does the property `fieldset`. I can't seen to find anywhere in the doc about the prop `fieldset`. Even looking through Chrome Dev tools I can't see where this property comes from.

How do you figure out which property does what. Is there and easy way to understand this with some example.

Is there a tutorial I can go through?

Answer (score 0):

`fieldset` is not a TextFields's property but a html tag from other component. if you check at Chrome Dev tools you can find `<fieldset>` with some css class.

TextFields is composed from other smaller components as you can check [text-fields - components](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#components). `fieldset` comes from the small component [OutlinedInput](https://material-ui.com/api/outlined-input/). it has the global css class `MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline` which you can find it at you [css list](https://material-ui.com/api/outlined-input/#css).

you can check at github [OutlinedInput implementation](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui/src/OutlinedInput).`fieldset` comes from NotchedOutline.js.

As you said, it's not explicit in the documentation. it doesn't list the tag elements composing a given component. It required me some investigation to dig deeper to find out its structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextField` `props` provided by `material-ui/core` actually:-

- `InputLabelProps`: to apply `styles` on **label**
- `InputProps`: to apply `styles` on **input** itself

this is an example of it:-

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { FormGroup, TextField } from '@material-ui/core'

const Demo = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  
  return (
    <FormGroup>
      <TextField 
        label="Name"
        variant="outlined"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} 
        required
        InputLabelProps={{
          classes: {
            root: classes.textFieldLabel,
            focused: classes.textFieldLabelFocused
          }
        }}
        InputProps={{
          classes: {
            root: classes.textFieldRoot,
            focused: classes.textFieldFocused,
            notchedOutline: classes.textFieldNotchedOutline
          }
        }}
      />
    </FormGroup>
  )
}

export default Demo

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  textFieldLabel: {
    // this will be applied when input focused (label color change)
    "&$textFieldLabelFocused": {
      color: theme.palette.secondary.main
    }
  },
  textFieldLabelFocused: {},
  textFieldRoot: {
    // this will be applied when hovered (input text color change)
    "&:hover": {
      color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    // this will applied when hovered (input border color change)
    "&:hover $textFieldNotchedOutline": {
      borderColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
    },
    // this will be applied when focused (input border color change)
    "&$textFieldFocused $textFieldNotchedOutline": {
      borderColor: theme.palette.secondary.main
    }
  },
  textFieldFocused: {},
  textFieldNotchedOutline: {}
}));
```

You can see it in this working [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-textfieldcssoverridematerialui?file=src/App.js) here